# ASP Request.QueryString doesn't html decode "&amp;" from URL query string

Tags: asp.net, query-string, decode, ampersand

In ASP having this URL:

```
http://www.example.com?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

`Request.QueryString["bar"]` returns NULL

The URL is a map area "href" link which I have assigned like so:

```
PolygonHotSpot p = new PolygonHotSpot();
p.NavigateUrl = http://www.example.com?foo=1&bar=2
```

ASP automatically HTML encodes the URL for the href, but it is not HTML decoding it again in the request therefore query string "bar" is not found.

Now I am using IIS URL Rewrite 2 module. Maybe this module is causing the problem? What can I do to solve it? I have tried using URL rewrite rules but couldn't figure our how or if it is the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea, but you could use `Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")` (or Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"] - your tags say ASP classic but your code looks like C#?) to get at the entire thing and then process it yourself.

I think there must be something deeper wrong though. A link can be encoded to be sent to the browser - the browser does the work of decoding it before navigating to the link. You can demonstrate this with a simple `<a href="/test?a=1&amp;b=2">` in a test script - the browser ends up correctly at `/test?a=1&b=2`. Testing it with a polygonal image map shows the same behaviour.

If you can show me what is in your actual HTML output for the image map I might be able to help more.